# 508 ADA Compliant - Way to skip content

Tags: javascript, css, html, section508

Say you have a list of updated items from a feed you're loading from an external resource that you know your ADA user would never care to hear read by their screen reader. Is there a way I'm not finding to let them skip that content, or even omit it from what a screen reader might look at that's still 508 compliant?

I know the "skip navigation" tricks, but would like to know another method for adhoc situations and am looking to be educated if someone knows a clean trick? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris - I recommend changing the language you are using. Referring to a person with a disability as an ADA user is akin to referring to an African American as a semi-derogitory name.

> loading from an external resource that you know your ADA user would never care to hear read by their screen reader.

Can you give some proof of  this rather large assumption? Taking out the fact we are talking about people with disabilities, the quoted line would read "I have a feature on my page that up to 20% of visitors won't care about." Most people will say then "why are you spending that much real estate on a feature? Axe it!"

> your ADA user would never care to hear read by their screen reader

This is also limited vision on your end. ADA Users, rather people with disabilities don't just use screen readers.

> Is there a way I'm not finding to let them skip that content, or even omit it from what a screen reader might look at that's still 508 compliant?

The best way to do this is the skip link method you mentioned. Pseudo code:

```
<a href="#jump" class="hidden">Skip over the useless feature</a>
<div>
  // code for the useless feature
</div>
<a name="jump" id="jump" tabindex="-1"></a>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
```

Then `.hidden` would be something like:

```
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.hidden:focus { left: 999px; }
```

Comment: Thank's for calling me out on the mis-use of terminology. I will be the first to admit my tact in the area of political correctness has probably never been good. I mean I still refer to both myself and others of my specific origin by a phrase that others would find offensive but I often forget even in this day and age others may take things more literal/critical than I do, so I appreciate your candor. As for the content, you would agree if you knew the particulars I'm sure. Either way, thanks again!

Comment: I repeat my question: if this part is really junk why ever include it? People with disabilities cover all walks of life. What if the user doesn't use a mouse? What you are doing is like saying "you suck, I have pre-determined that you're not good enough to view this." I agree that if it is something like a Twiiter feed, most won't care, and providing a skip link is a nice idea, but you should *never* make the assumption you are alluding to.

Comment: The site itself is for a very targeted audience, the content in question is just a feed of while albeit associative info it's mainly there for the mere purpose of fluff to intentionally add real estate and is not pertinent. My thought, is (regardless of their personal situation) why waste their time with it when generally probably 98% of any visitors would just look right past it anyway since as I said...it's obviously just there to add some real estate in the first place (which is not my choice to make.) Please do not interpret any kind of favoritism either way. Cheers!

Comment: use the strategy i mentioned above then

Answer (score 0):

Place a heading tag at the beginning of the "important" content so that it can easily be jumped to. As a screen reader user I commonly navigate pages by heading as a more reliable way to skip boilerplate content. Anchors don't always work; sometimes they send you to a random location on the page or just do nothing.